# How to check if test is failing in XUnit

Tags: c#, xunit

I have a C# code base with integration tests that use TestContainers to stand up the application and has MELT shimmed in for easy looks into logs.  My application includes LocalStack for AWS SNS/SQS integration testing.

The integration tests hit the public endpoints of the application and use LocalStack to send fake events or listen to events to know that the API worked correctly.

Sometimes if an error occurs on the back end the API can still return a valid (cached, for example) response to the user.

Sometimes the test does not explicitly know why a test has failed.  For example, when the test is waiting for LocalStack to receive a specific event but it times out.  When this happens, the only information XUnit includes is "Operation timed out".

When this occurs, I can scan the MELT logs for magic strings and include them in the test failure.

To do this, the `WebApplicationFactory` has

```
public override async ValueTask DisposeAsync() {
    var messages = LogSink.LogEntries
        .Where(l => /* Check l.Message against a magic list*/)
        .Select(l => ...);

    if (messages.Any()) {
        Assert.Fail(messages.Aggregate((sum, next) => $"{sum}{Environment.NewLine}{next}"));
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes an error doesn't / shouldn't fail a test.  I may have error handling in code that returns default or cached data and should succeed - but the error still might have been logged.

I currently have an issue where if don't add a magic string to the list then I have a test that fails with no information, and if I do then I have another test that now fails because of an error that was logged but didn't affect the result of the test so it would have succeeded if not for the `DispseAsync...Assert.Fail`.

What I want to do is this:

```
public override async ValueTask DisposeAsync() {
    if (XUnit.TestContext.Current.IsFailing) { // <== How do I do this?
        var messages = LogSink.LogEntries
            .Where(l => l.LogLevel >= LogLevel.Error)
            .Select(l => ...);

        if (messages.Any()) {
            Assert.Fail(messages.Aggregate((sum, next) => $"{sum}{Environment.NewLine}{next}"));
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do this from `DisposeAsync` so that every single test receives this behavior.

Is this possible?  I guess it doesn't have to `DisposeAsync`, if XUnit has an 'OnTestFail' handler that might work.

Thanks.